# Replay button doesn't work. (Swift, SpriteKit)

Tags: iphone, swift, sprite-kit

Once my game ends, it displays a button for replay, but I can't understand how to let Xcode know if there is a touch after the game has ended. My replay button's code is in didBeginContact Method and is as follows:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
       if (.....) {
            ..........
      }  else {
         replayButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ReplayButton")
            replayButton.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 1.75, y: size.height / 2.5)
            replayButton.name = "replayButton"
            self.addChild(replayButton)
       }
```

New Swift file:

```
class button: SKSprideNode {

let replayButton = button(imageNamed: "replayButton")


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

var touch = touches as!  Set<UITouch>
var location = touch.first!.locationInNode(self)
var node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)


if (node.name == "replayButton") {

    let myScene = EMode(size: self.size)
    let reveal = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(2.0)
    self.scene!.view(myScene, transition: reveal)  //error on this line
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the replay button's user interaction enabled to true like this:

```
replayButton.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Then you just need to listen for when the button or scene is touched. One way to do that is make a subclass of `SKSpriteNode` called `Button` or something, and override the `touchesBegan` method.

EXAMPLE:

**ButtonClass**

```
class ExampleButton: SKSpriteNode {
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        //do stuff here
    }
}
```

**Button Initialization**

```
let button = ExampleButton(imageNamed: "ButtonImage")
button.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: Hey, so it still didn't work. I added the "replayButton.userInteractionEnabled = true" to my actual class and then created a new file and made a subclass in it. I also did add Import SpriteKit on top of the code. I have added my new code to the question. Can you please look at it and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why is the superclass mode?

Comment: Opps, I made a typo. It is EMode.

Comment: I think you meant to do SKSpriteMode or something

Comment: I think I'm getting confused. Bare with me please. I'm fairly new to this. My main class is : class EMode: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate { ..... }

Comment: I had initially tried putting the code inside touches began in my main class, but it only works if the game starts and ends right away. That's  when the replay button does work, but if the game was to go on for more then, lets say, three seconds, Xcode doesn't know if there is a touch on replay button node.

Comment: I added an example of what I am talking about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85138/discussion-between-sharukh-and-kendel).

Comment: I did what you said, but then it gives me an error saying, button doesn't have a member named "view".

Comment: Where are you trying to assign a view value? Why?

Comment: It's in the subclass's touchesBegan method, which is when the replay button is touched, it will transition to another scene. It the last line in touchesBegan.

Comment: Do self.scene!.view instead

Comment: Gave me an error again saying, cannot invoke 'view' with an argument list of type '(EMode, transition:SKTransition)'. Hey, I really appreciate for helping me out :)

Comment: What exactly is Emode?

Comment: Oh its just a scene I named, where all the game play takes place.

Comment: Yeah sure. Hey, so I'm really confused to how to do this and don't understand to why I need to make a new class for sprite kit to get this to working. Why wouldn't just saying that if there is a touch on the replay button node in touchesBegan, it would just transition the way I want or run the code for the button?

Comment: This isn't the only way to solve the issue, this is just one solution which I find works for me (and many others). This is just a suggestion you are more than welcome to use other methods.

Comment: You shouldn't be using a node variable. The node is self.